# How to retrieve value between tokens

Tags: arrays, c, string, token

I have a question about tokens. I created this programme that splits a sentence based on the token "[ ]". Is it possible however to retrieve the character in between it? Example, I would like to retrieve the number 5000 from the input [5000] where "[ ]" is the barrier token so I can assign that number to a variable later on. This is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   char str[ ] = "My balance is [5000]";
   const char s[ ] = "[]";
   char *token;

   
   token = strtok(str, s);

  
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

EDIT: Basically I would like to know how I can assign the value in "[ ]" to a variable. Lets say I'm using fgets to prompt the user to key in an entire sentence with their balance in brackets [ ]. How do i create a programme that retrieves that value in the parenthesis and assigns it to a value?

Comment: The code outputs `5000` on the second line. You are extracting the string `5000`.

Comment: What result did you get? Did you see `5000` in the output? With that result what else do you need to know? Just save that result into a variable.

Comment: `"[]"` is not the _"barrier token"_, but the string will be split into tokens delimited by the characters `[` and `]`. The first token is `"My balance is "`, the second token is `"5000"` (what you want to retrieve).

Comment: @kaylum  How tho? its techincally breaking an entire sentence into 3 parts. Like if I were to use an fgets function instead, how would it know which one to assign to the variable?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Not "barrier token", got it! But how do I specifically assign the value in "[ ]" to a variable? Lets say I were to use fgets where the user keys in an entire sentence and brackets the number, how can I programme it to retrieve that number specifically?

Comment: @Alicia read the chapter dealing with strings in your learning material. Probably you want something like: `char foo[100]; ... strcpy(foo, token);`. The `5000` between `[]` is obviously the second token.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Okay, I'll do some reading on that. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user3121023 Will give that a shot. Need to learn about it first xD Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `strchr` to find a `[`. It returns NULL if not found or a pointer to the `[`.
`strcspn` can be used to locate a `]`. Then `strncpy` to extract the string between the delimiters.
`strtol` could also be used to parse a number. It can give a pointer to the trailing character which in this case would be a `]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char str[ ] = "My balance is [5000]";
    char out[sizeof str] = "";
    const char s[ ] = "[]";
    char *token;
    char *last;

    if ( ( token = strchr ( str, s[0]))) {//find [
        ++token;//advance to next character past [
        int count = strcspn ( token, &s[1]);//count characters to ]
        if ( token[count]) {//not the terminating zero
            strncpy ( out, token, sizeof out);
            out[count] = 0;
            //printf ( "%.*s\n", count, token);
            printf ( "out %s\n", out);
        }
        else {
            printf ( "could not find %c\n", s[1]);
        }

        long number = strtol ( token, &last, 10);
        if ( last == token) {
            printf ( "could not parse a number\n");
        }
        else if ( *last != s[1]) {
            printf ( "missing/misplaced delimiter\n");
        }
        else printf ( "number %ld\n", number);
    }
    else {
        printf ( "could not find %c\n", s[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a bunch for this! I'll spend some time to understand your code before improving mine. Thanks again :)